# Editing Flexslider HTML

Tags: flexslider

I'm still new to coding. I downloaded flex slider, and I have it running fine on my site and working fine. However I can't make ANY edits into my html regarding the slider. It has the 'next' and 'previous' image links on my gallery, which I would like to replace. It shows up in the html when I inspect it in firebug, yet when I run my html through my text editor (Im using text mate), it doesn't show up at all!

Any ideas why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the navigational arrows on the left and right side of the images. This can be changes in the "flexslider.css" file.  If you are using textmate then the line number is 52.

Probably the easiest way is to find the image here images/bg_direction_nav.png. Right click the image and open with your image editing software eg. photoshop. Then once you have change the image just save it and it will be saved in the same folder location. If you keep the image the same size then you will not have to mess around with anything else..